# Loading plist into core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have the code to actually load the data from my plist into the entity in core data. But where I seem to be stumbling finding any latest posts or info is how to check to see if that entity already contains the data/time to load the data into core data. I can only seem to find outdated non swift fetchrequests to check I don't read anything non swift so I have no idea how to sequence them in swift language....If you need to look at the code I have to actually load the data I can provide it. I know how to read the plist but as far as actually loading the plist to core data is where I am needing the help.

Comment: In general, you would be well served to learn how to read objective c so that you can convert their code to swift. Just for future reference.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you are asking. Do you want to know how to look in your core data database to see if your data has been loaded?

Comment: I want to actually have the controller check to see if my objects from the plist have already been loaded lets say I have a total of 565 objects I want to have a check to in place to see if those objects already exist in the entity after the initial load up then if they are not = load into the entity with the func that was created to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let databaseAlreadyCreated = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("databaseAlreadyCreated")
if !databaseAlreadyCreated {
    //call your function to setup your core data database
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"databaseAlreadyCreated")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

That's the simplest approach. You can also create another entity for your Core Data which will store applications settings.

Finally, you can try to fetch your entity and if it exists - it means you have already created it. If the results count is 0 - it means that you have to set it up.

Comment: This is what I've done in the past. Super easy and not much code.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for thanks! My only problem I am trying to figure out the line `if !databaseAlreadyCreated { doesn't work though it says expected declaration.

Comment: Never mind I got the method to work finally I have been having the worst headaches the last 2 days so I wasn't reading code properly